# Not allowed to load local resource: chrome-error://chromewebdata/favicon@2x.png chrome-error://chromewebdata/

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, progressive-web-apps, service-worker

I'm following [PWA tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Progressive_web_apps/Offline_Service_workers) and the same way implemented offline storage.
In addition to the specified error, I got the following warnings

```
The FetchEvent for "https://localhost:7047/Shop/Catalog" resulted in a network error response: an object that was not a Response was passed to respondWith().
```

I have web manifest installed with content:

```
{
    "name": "To table",
    "short_name": "To table",
    "description": "Excellent marketplace",
    "icons": [
        {
            "src": "/android-chrome-192x192.png",
            "sizes": "192x192",
            "type": "image/png",
            "purpose": "maskable"
        },
        {
            "src": "/android-chrome-512x512.png",
            "sizes": "512x512",
            "type": "image/png"
        }
    ],
    "theme_color": "#ffffff",
    "background_color": "#ffffff",
    "start_url": "/",
    "display": "standalone"
}
```

I have these tags in my layout and corresponding images in specified folders.

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/apple-touch-icon.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="/favicon-32x32.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="/favicon-16x16.png">
<link rel="manifest" href="/site.webmanifest">
<link rel="mask-icon" href="/safari-pinned-tab.svg" color="#5bbad5">
<meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#da532c">
<meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a mistake in code. I forgot to call handler of `respondWith`:

```
self.addEventListener(`fetch`, (e: any) => {
    e.respondWith((async () => {
        const r = await caches.match(e.request)
        if (r) {
            return r
        }
        const response = await fetch(e.request)
        const cache = await caches.open(cacheName)
        cache.put(e.request, response.clone())
        return response
    }))
})
```

Correct:

```
self.addEventListener(`fetch`, (e: any) => {
    e.respondWith((async () => {
        const r = await caches.match(e.request)
        if (r) {
            return r
        }
        const response = await fetch(e.request)
        const cache = await caches.open(cacheName)
        cache.put(e.request, response.clone())
        return response
    })())
})
```